# Knockout binding/mapping failing, sending null to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, knockout.js

I am attempting to using knockout to create a client side model so client side validation can be done on the needed attributes, some of which are nested and or in nested lists of other models.

In following some guides and patterns, I have tried to map a test list from the main view model and send it back to the controller when the form submits, with validation that would prevent the form from being submitted if the value is null.

When the form is submitted, not only does it fail to validate with the current set up, the edited values (which are correctly populated in the view on load, so some type of binding is correctly working) return as null in the controller.

```
namespace KnockoutDemo.Models
{
    public class XmlParameter
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase XmlValue;
        public string Name;
    }
}


public class TestStepViewModel
{
    public int TestStepId { get; set; }
    public string TestStepName { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public List<XmlParameter> XmlParameters { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax
@using System.Activities.Expressions
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization

@model KnockoutDemo.Models.TestStepViewModel



@{ string data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);}



@section scripts
{

    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/teststepviewmodel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var testStepViewModel = new TestStepViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
        ko.applyBindings(testStepViewModel);
    </script>
}

<form>

    <div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="TestStepName">Test Step Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="TestStepName" id="TestStepName" data-bind="value: TestStepName"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="TestStepName">Test Step Id:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="TestStepId" id="TestStepId" data-bind="value: TestStepId" disabled="disabled"/>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Product Code</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: XmlParameters">
            <tr>
                <td class="form-group"><input name="Name" class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="attr: {'id': 'Name_' + $index()}, value: Name"/></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

    <p><button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: save" type="submit" >Save</button></p>
</form>
```

teststepviewmodel.js + validation

```
TestStepViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    self.save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Save/",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: "application/json"

        });
    }
}


var XmlParameter = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self);
}


var mapping = {
    'XmlParameters': {
        key: function (xmlParameters) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(xmlParameters.Name);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new XmlParameter(options.data);
        }
    }
};



$("form").validate({
        submithandler: function () {
            testStepViewModel.save();
        },
        rules: {
            TestStepName: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 30

            },
            Value: {
                required: true

            },
            XmlValue: {
                required: true
            }   
        },

    messages: {
        TestStepName: {
            required: "A Test Step must have a non-null value, please enter a name"
        },
        Value: {
            required: "The parameter can't be null/empty"
        }
    }
});
```

The JsonResult Save() controller correctly populates the Id and Test Step Name, however the XmlParameters are both null.

Controllers (Like I said, this is simply a test to return knockout model with client side validation, so I'm simply populating a view model on load and setting a breakpoint on the JsonResult to see the contents of the model)

```
public ActionResult Index(TestStepViewModel ts)
        {
            TestStepViewModel testStepViewModel = new TestStepViewModel
            {
                TestStepName = "Editing A Test Step",
                TestStepId = 10,
                Message = "Hello, this is a message"
            };
            testStepViewModel.XmlParameters = new List<XmlParameter>();

            testStepViewModel.XmlParameters.Add(new XmlParameter
            {
                Name = "Xml P1"
            });

            testStepViewModel.XmlParameters.Add(new XmlParameter
            {
                Name = "Xml P2"
            });



            return View("Index", testStepViewModel);

        }

        public JsonResult Save(TestStepViewModel testStepViewModel)
        {
            return null;
        }
```